# Presenting SKScene BAD ACCESS crash

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, exc-bad-access, skscene, sknode

I'm building a fairly simple game in SpriteKit. This is my first experience with SpriteKit and so far it has gone smoothly. I have gotten to the point now that I want to present a new SKScene when the player completes the game. I'm getting a Bad Access crash that I can't seem to diagnose.

I think I am presenting the scene correctly:

```
UnlockRockets *scene = [[UnlockRockets alloc] initWithSize:self.scene.size];
[self.view presentScene:scene];
```

Every time I get the following error on the presentScene: line - Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0x10)

Looking at the thread trace it appears the crash might be originating at [SKNode isPaused]

Any advice would be great, I'm completely lost on this one.

Comment: My guess is that your problem is not **how** you're presenting your `SKScene`, but **where**. What method calls that code?

Comment: I'm calling it in the didBeginContact function, is that not the best place to call it from?

Comment: Just making sure you got it right: that `UnlockRockets` scene is supposed to be some other screen in your game, right? If that's the case, then it should work. Maybe you have something wrong in the `UnlockRockets` scene.

Comment: Try this:  SKScene *scene = [[UnlockRockets alloc] initWithSize:self.size];

Comment: Tried that, still no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

i think problem in your initWithSize method inside UnlockRockets class

Comment: I've commented everything out of the initWithSize method other than setting the background color to check this. It still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue with SKView present scene, even when scene was absolutely new without any configurations. So I solved it by using this.

```
    myScene *newScene = [myScene sceneWithSize:size];
    newScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;
    SKView *currentskView = (SKView*)  self.scene.view;
    SKScene *currentScene = (SKScene*) self.scene;
    [currentScene removeAllChildren];
    [currentScene removeFromParent];
    [currentskView presentScene:newScene];
```

also I've noticed that if declare strong reference for the scene - it's works in the way you did, but in that case scene live in memory even if it's invisible, and xCode notifies that there are memory warnings.